# how to generate coordinates between two points

Tags: python-3.x, list, coordinates, chess

I am attempting to make my own Chess game and would like to know how to generate coordinates between two points.

```
list_coordinates = []
first_coordinate = [2, 7]
second_coordinate = [7, 2]
```

I want list_coordinates to have the value:

```
list_coordinates = [[3, 6], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 3]]
```

But I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Which programming language do you use? What should happen when the coordinates are neither diagonal nor on the same row or column?

Comment: It is not clear. What about finding the square where the two pieces are on opposite vertices, and than getting the grid inside such square?

Comment: I want to generate these coordinates to check for obstructing pieces when I choose to move the bishop - since it cannot 'jump' over other pieces in the game.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Phyton. Therefore, I explain the mathematics behind the question. In chess, there are 8 directions for the linies, rows and diagonals:

[image]

You can calculate the direction between two fields [x1, y1] and [x2, y2] like this:

```
delta_x = x2 - x1
delta_y = y2 - y1
```

Now check, if the two fields are lying on a row, line or diagonal:

```
if delta_x = 0 or delta_y = 0 or ABS(delta_x) = ABS(delta_y) then
  dir = [SGN(delta_x), SGN(delta_y)]
else
  dir = 0
end if
```

with SGN(z) returns +1, if z > 0, -1 if z < 0 or 0 if z= 0
and  ABS(z) returns the absolute value of z.

Now dir is the direction from field [x1, y1] to [x2, y2] or dir = 0 because, the both fields are not lying on the same row, line or diagonal. To find all fields between the two fields, you can use a loop:

```
[x , y] = [x1, y1] 
loop 
  [x, y] = [x, y] + dir    ' a field between the two given fields.
until [x, y] = [x2, x2]
```